# How can I count array values from mysql query in PHP and associate a second column with the count results

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is select * from table then get the count of duplicate rows in a column but also have another column (make) associated with the results.

Eg:

### Desired output:

**Make** **Model** **Qty**

Ford   Focus   3

Ford   Fiesta  5

Ford   Mondeo  1

BMW    M3      1

Audi   A4      2

Audi   A3      4

### Current output:

**Model** **Qty**

Focus   3

Fiesta  5

Mondeo  1

M3      1

A4      2

A3      4

## My code:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$modelArray = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $modelArray[] = $row['model'];

}

$result = array_count_values($modelArray);

foreach ($result as $model=>$qty) {

    echo $model." ".$qty;

}
```

I don't know how to also include the 'make' column in my results using the array_count_values() function.

I think I may be going about this the wrong way as it would appear to be a fairly common task but I can't find any information on how to do it like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do you select the columns that you want in your SQL? As it seems to me you're just selection the 'model' field thous you can only display the 'model' field.

Comment: The first line of my question states I am using select * from my table. So yes the Make column is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guest what you are trying to do is a `GROUP BY` statement. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html)
I guest your current query is `SELECT make, model FROM table`.
Then you count repeating data using `array_count_values`.
I think you need to change the query using GROUP BY statement like this.

```
SELECT make, model, COUNT(1) AS qty FROM table GROUP BY make, model
```

Using that query, you can echo the result using this code.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    echo $row['make'] . " " . $row['model'] . " " . $row['qty'];

}
```

Comment: I thought there must be a simpler way to it and this is it. Thank you this is perfect. Tested and working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php 
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $modelArray = [];
    $makes = []
    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        $modelArray[] = $row['model'];
        $makes[$row['model']]=$row['make'];

    }

    $result = array_count_values($modelArray);

    foreach ($result as $model=>$qty) {

        echo $makes[$model]." ".$model." ".$qty;

    }
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks, this did work but the accepted answer was better because of the explanation and changing the database query was the better approach.